# Using socket2 with hyper

Tags: sockets, rust, unix-socket, hyper

I am writing a http server that works with it's host machine via a unix domain sockets. The server is written using hyper and I am connecting to UDS via socket2.

This is my code:

```
let socket = Socket::new(Domain::UNIX, Type::STREAM, None)?;
let socket_address = SockAddr::unix("unix://tmp/test.sock")?;
socket.bind(&socket_address)?;
socket.listen(128)?;
let server = hyper::server::Server::builder(socket.into()).serve(service);
```

What is the right way to do this? I am getting an error saying **cannot infer type for type parameter `I`**

```
error[E0698]: type inside `async fn` body must be known in this context
  --> src/server.rs:65:64
   |
65 |     let server = hyper::server::Server::builder(socket.into()).serve(service);
   |                                                                ^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `I`
   |
note: the type is part of the `async fn` body because of this `await`
  --> src/server.rs:66:13
   |
66 |     let _ = server.await?;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`I` is the generic parameter to `hyper::server::Server`. While I am aware what is causing the issue: compiler not able to determine what does `socket.into()` get cast to, I don't know to solve it.

Please correct if my understanding is wrong. Can I get some help in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the socket into a type such as [`tokio::net::UnixListener`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1/tokio/net/struct.UnixListener.html). Once you have done this, you need an implementation of the [`Accept`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14/hyper/server/accept/trait.Accept.html) trait. You can implement that trait in the following manner:

```
use hyper::server::accept::Accept;
use tokio::net::UnixListener;

use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};

pub struct UDSAccept {
    inner: UnixListener,
}

impl Accept for UDSAccept {
    type Conn = tokio::net::UnixStream;
    type Error = std::io::Error;

    fn poll_accept(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<Option<Result<Self::Conn, Self::Error>>> {
        match self.inner.poll_accept(cx) {
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
            Poll::Ready(Ok((socket, _addr))) => Poll::Ready(Some(Ok(socket))),
            Poll::Ready(Err(err)) => Poll::Ready(Some(Err(err))),
        }
    }
}
```

The above type will be usable as the argument to `Server::builder`.

If the constructor that comes with the Tokio type does not provide all the options you need and you still wish to use `socket2` to construct it, you can do so by first converting it to the std `UnixListener` and then calling Tokio's [`from_std`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1/tokio/net/struct.UnixListener.html#method.from_std) method. Be aware that you must set the socket in non-blocking mode yourself when doing this!

Comment: I was inclined towards using `socket2` for this, but setting it non-blocking and do other zoo-keeping was out of the scope of the work. Hence, I went with a `UnixListener` and implemented Accept over it. Thanks!